# React JSON based form stuck with setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have already made a json base form in react. When I try to add my state the change event, it only shows the actual element.
I have 3 input fields that I would like to put in my state.SERVICE object.

```
    state = {
        SERVICES: [],
        ITEMS: []
      };


    handleChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        this.setState({ [name]: value }); 
    //It shows all the elements {name:1,name:2.....}
    }

//If try to add it my SERVICES it only shows the actual element


this.setState({ SERVICES: { [name]: value } }); 

//output: SERVICES:name: "2" //this is the problem

//Expected:
SERVICES:[
{name: "1"},
{name: "2"},
{name: "3"}]
```

I tried to concat it to an array, but it contains all the input field changes:

Answer (score 0):

Spread the current value into that object as well:

```
this.setState({ SERVICES: { ...this.state.SERVICES, [name]: value } });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it before, but it concat all the inputfield changes. If I type somthing it  add a new array element:
0: {c1: "s"}
1: {c1: "so"}
2: {c1: "som"}
3: {c1: "some"}
4: {c2: "t"}
5: {c2: "th"}
6: {c2: "thi"}
7: {c2: "thin"}
8: {c2: "thing"}
9: {c3: "w"}
10: {c3: "wr"}
11: {c3: "wro"}
12: {c3: "wron"}
this.setState({ [name]: value }); output= c1: "some", c2: "thing", c3: "wrong",

I would like something like this: SERVICES: Array(3)
0: {c1: "some"}
1: {c2: "thing"}
2: {c3: "wrong"}

Comment: Oh, interesting. So why isn't your `SERVICES` state property an object instead of an array? This would be a lot easier if your object was `{ c1: "some", c2: "thing", c3: wrong }` rather than `[{ c1: "some" }, { c2: "thing" }, { c3: "wrong" }]`?

Comment: I changed the SERVICES state to an object but, how can I add it? If try to add i got an error message TypeError: this.state.SERVICES is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a new services array and then add the new item to it. One way to do this is by using the spread operator `...` and then adding the new item to the end.

```
const newServices = [...this.state.SERVICES, { [name]: value }];
this.setState({ SERVICES: newServices });
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the issue? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it before, but it concat all the inputfield changes. If I type somthing it  add a new array element:
0: {c1: "s"}
1: {c1: "so"}
2: {c1: "som"}
3: {c1: "some"}
4: {c2: "t"}
5: {c2: "th"}
6: {c2: "thi"}
7: {c2: "thin"}
8: {c2: "thing"}
9: {c3: "w"}
10: {c3: "wr"}
11: {c3: "wro"}
12: {c3: "wron"}
this.setState({ [name]: value }); output= c1: "some", c2: "thing", c3: "wrong",

I would like something like this: SERVICES: Array(3)
0: {c1: "some"}
1: {c2: "thing"}
2: {c3: "wrong"}